# Null value in column "Name" of relation "Orders" violates not-null constraint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, null

in the code I wrote, it shows that the "Name" property is empty in the file named Order.cs. But I get the same error even though I throw the "Name" attribute to Order.cs

The error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
     ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23502: null value in column "Name" of relation "Orders" violates not-null constraint

DETAIL: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|234_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 23502
    MessageText: null value in column "Name" of relation "Orders" violates not-null constraint
    Detail: Detail redacted as it may contain sensitive data. Specify 'Include Error Detail' in the connection string to include this information.
    SchemaName: public
    TableName: Orders
    ColumnName: Name
    File: execMain.c
    Line: 1968
    Routine: ExecConstraints
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at RentAPI.Persistence.Contexts.RentAPIDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ahmet-rent\RentAPI\Infrastructure\RentAPI.Persistence\Contexts\RentAPIDbContext.cs:line 35
   at RentAPI.Persistence.Repositories.WriteRepository`1.SaveAsync() in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ahmet-rent\RentAPI\Infrastructure\RentAPI.Persistence\Repositories\WriteRepository.cs:line 55
   at RentAPI.API.Controllers.ProductsController.Get() in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ahmet-rent\RentAPI\Presentation\RentAPI.API\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7035
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zsdch
Accept-Language: tr,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Referer: https://localhost:7035/swagger/index.html
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Microsoft Edge";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

My Customer.cs files:

```
using RentAPI.Domain.Entities.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RentAPI.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Customer : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ProductsController.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RentAPI.Application.Repositories;
using RentAPI.Domain.Entities;

namespace RentAPI.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly private IProductWriteRepository _productWriteRepository;
        readonly private IProductReadRepository _productReadRepository;

        readonly private IOrderWriteRepository _orderWriteRepository;

        readonly private ICustomerWriteRepository _customerWriteRepository;

        public ProductsController(
            IProductWriteRepository productWriteRepository,
            IProductReadRepository productReadRepository,
            IOrderWriteRepository orderWriteRepository,
            ICustomerWriteRepository customerWriteRepository)
        {
            _productWriteRepository = productWriteRepository;
            _productReadRepository = productReadRepository;
            _orderWriteRepository = orderWriteRepository;
            _customerWriteRepository = customerWriteRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
            await _customerWriteRepository.AddAsync(new() { Id = customerId, Name = "Ahmet" });

            await  _orderWriteRepository.AddAsync(new() { Description = "bla bla bla", Address = "Antalya Korkuteli", CustomerId = customerId});
            await  _orderWriteRepository.AddAsync(new() { Description = "bla bla bla 2", Address = "Antalya Alanya", CustomerId = customerId});
            await  _orderWriteRepository.SaveAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

My Order.cs file

```
using RentAPI.Domain.Entities.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RentAPI.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Order : BaseEntity
    {
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Before I got this error, there was a problem with the database, so I deleted the database and migrations. Then I prevented the previous problem by creating 1 migrations again. Then, when I ran it to print a name in the database, Name = "Ahmet", I got the error that it was accepted as null.

Should I add the name string that I added to the Customer.cs file to the Order.cs file?

After some more research, the problem is caused by the name column in the table named orders in the database, but I still couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the error you see the line:

```
  MessageText: null value in column "Name" of relation "Orders" violates not-null constraint
```

So you don't show the data model of your database at all (this would be useful in understanding the problem), however from this error message we can see there is a relation called Orders that requires a column Name to not be null.  That is the problem.  Look at the relation definition in the DB to find out what table the Name column is in and that will make the problem clearer.  If you want more help than this on this website please include all information about the data model (that is all the DDLs that would describe the table, indexes and constraints)

Comment: I understood what you said a little bit, but I don't know much about c# and database because I'm doing a project on a video. Could you please tell me the steps to fix this issue?

Comment: No.  In order to work with a DB and use this website you need to understand what I mean when you have to show the data model and the DDLs.  Do some google searches and learn how.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the error. As you said i maked the Name to not be null and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The `Order` object has a `Customer` Object, and a list of `Products`.

In order to find the root cause...

1. check that when you update the database, the *Name* property of the `Customer` object is populated.  If it is blank then you will need to set a value.
2. check that the `Product` object has a *Name* property.  If it does then you should ensure this has a value and not a null.